# Is this mechanical puzzle (Loony loop) solvable?

Tags: puzzle

["The aim of this puzzle is to free the tied cord from the figure-eight metal loop, without breaking or untying the cord."](http://home.comcast.net/~stegmann/tanglement.htm#fig8)

[image]

Comment: If it is solvable I imagine explaining the steps adequately would require an image program or a how-to video... or an audience of knot theorists.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This](http://sma.epfl.ch/~ojangure/Notes.pdf) says it's impossible.

Comment: Oh, the notorious Inta Bertuccioni! I *should* have remembered...